# Cuda cudaMemcpy2DArrayToArray does not have an asynchronous counterpart

Tags: cuda

I'm using: cudaMemcpy2DArrayToArray(). Is there also an asynchronous counterpart of this function? cudaMemcpy2DArrayToArrayAsync() does, not exist. I want to avoid implicit synchronization of my cuda operations.

Comment: It seems you have answered your own question.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that you cannot asynchronously copy a cuda array to another cuda array. I want to avoid synchronization at all costs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other 10 or so cudaMemcpy*() calls all have an async version so my guess is that this call is implemented in some way that prevents a fully async version. Note, though, that the docs say that "This function exhibits synchronous behavior for **most** use cases" and, by that, they seem to mean:

1. For transfers from pageable host memory to device memory, a stream sync is performed before the copy is initiated. The function will return once the pageable buffer has been copied to the staging memory for DMA transfer to device memory, but the DMA to final destination may not have completed.
2. For transfers from pinned host memory to device memory, the function is synchronous with respect to the host.
3. For transfers from device to either pageable or pinned host memory, the function returns only once the copy has completed.
4. For transfers from device memory to device memory, no host-side synchronization is performed.
5. For transfers from any host memory to any host memory, the function is fully synchronous with respect to the host.